# Aninhamento (nesting) é uma funcionalidade especifica do SASS?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, sass

Acabei de terminar um curso de Bootstrap e fiquei com uma dúvida: o aninhamento ([nesting](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/style-rules)) é uma funcionalidade específica do [SASS](https://sass-lang.com/)? Pelo o que eu entendi [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4564916/nesting-css-classes), sim.

Digo isso, porque ao usar [Media Queries](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/overview/) em conjunto com o Bootstrap eu tenho a possibilidade de fazer algo deste tipo para alterar elementos de acordo com o tamanho da tela. No código abaixo estou dizendo que os elementos vão se alterar em telas **pequenas**.

```
/*// Small devices (landscape phones, 576px and up)*/
@media (min-width: 576px) and (max-width: 767.98px) {
    h1{
        font-size: 3em;
    }

    .btn-custom{
        margin: 10px 15px;
    }
}
```

Minha dúvida é: isso é aninhamento? Estou usando o SASS?

Comment: Isso não é uma aninhamento de classes, isso é uma regra de view-port

Comment: Obrigado hugocsl! :)

Answer (score -2):

O @media está tanto em css quanto em Sass ele serve para dar responsividade há sua página. O Sass nada mais é que um pré-processador de css, ele muda um pouquinho o jeito de se escrever css (eu diria que melhora um pouco).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aqui está uma imagem da diferença de Sass e css, você irá notar que a diferença é pouca e também que o Sass torna o código de estilização mais organizado e você também tem a opção de reutilizar código sem precisar sempre digita-lo.

Comment: Legal Matheus, então isso quer dizer que nas Media Queries do código que eu postei não está sendo implementado o aninhamento, está correto?

Comment: Aninhar é o ato de você alinhar e organizar o código ali na sua tela, e o Sass trás esse aninhamento de forma a facilitar a sua visão sobre o código. Mas de todo modo seu código está aninhado e organizado como um bom desenvolvedor deve sempre fazer. :)

Comment: Entendi Matheus, muito obrigado pela explicação.